# Composer ignore minimum stable

Tags: symfony, dependencies, composer-php, bundle, command-line-interface

I get following error on composer install for ebay bundle. dependency has old version of jms and I'm using new version. what can I do on this?

How can I ignore dependency?

```
- webconsul/ebay-api-bundle dev-master requires jms/serializer-bundle ~0.13 -> no matching package found.
```

my composer.json:

```
    "jms/serializer-bundle":                "^1.1",
     ...
    "webconsul/ebay-api-bundle":            "dev-master"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a reason why `jms/serializer-bundle` had a major release. They are simply incompatible. You can't ignore the version, because the code won't work anymore.

Either contribute the update to `webconsul/ebay-api-bundle` or create a working fork if it's not maintained anymore.

Comment: I have created the fork for this bundle. how can I use composer to install it?  username/ebay-api...?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot ignore version restriction required by a dependency that you are trying to install.

The classic way in this case is to look for a more recent version of the requested package (here `webconsul/ebay-api-bundle`).
But, you are using `dev-master` and it should be the most recent dev version.

You can just wait for a new version or adapt your `jms/serializer-bundle` version according to the `webconsul/ebay-api-bundle` requirement.

**EDIT** By using `dev-master` or `@dev` you will have a non stable release.

Comment: `dev` never equals `stable`.

Comment: The minimum stability of the requested package is not specified as requirement for answers, only how get around `webconsol/ebay-api-bundle` requirements.
So I think it's good to propose it, also I've edited my answer to specify it may return a non stable release.

Comment: I just saw this: _But, you are using dev-master and it should be the newer stable version._ That's why my comment.

Comment: You are right, thank's @malcolm. I've added corrections.